# How to retrieve dict with the row column and value of table in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have the following table in a Tkinter Gui and I wanted to know how I would be able to get a dict with all of the values in each of the cells and the corresponding row and col of each value in the dict as well. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as Tkinter
import random

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Tkinter.Frame(master)

        self.data_readout = Tkinter.Button(frame, text="Collect Data", bd=10, height=2, width=10, command=lambda: self.dataReadout(self.table_values))
        self.data_readout.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.table_values = Tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Values", borderwidth=10, relief=Tkinter.GROOVE, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.table_values.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        for i in range(4): #Rows
            for j in range(10): #Columns
                b = Tkinter.Entry(self.table_values, text="", width=5)
                b.grid(row=i, column=j)
                b.insert(0, str(round(random.random()*100)))

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

    def dataReadout(self, frame):
        #returns Dict of row and column
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you mean _after_ the creation of them?

Comment: Yes after the creation of them

Comment: Are you aware that you are able to reference _only_ the very last entry you've created with `b`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], above code isn't very long but it can be minimized still.

Comment: @Nae i was unaware of that do you have any suggestions for creating a table that would be able to store data in tkinter and also be able to be mutated.

Comment: I'd lose `dataReadout` and button and frames too. Then appoint `master` as the entry's master `Tkinter.Entry(master, ...)`.

Comment: Yes, you _can_.  I'd go with a `list`, in this case. Create it however you'd create a list of numbers, except this time the numbers, are replaced with `Tkinter.Entry(...)` then you can also easily use `grid` like `b[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j)`. Then It should be trivial to `b[i][j].get()` to get the value in that entry and `b[i][j]` refers to an exact widget anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Below is a minimal example that creates the `Entry` fields as a two-dimensional list, and later puts one of the values in a label:

```
import tkinter as Tkinter
import random

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.b = list()
        for i in range(4): #Rows
            self.b.append(list())        # to add the 2nd dimension to ith element
            for j in range(10): #Columns
                self.b[i].append(Tkinter.Entry(master, text="", width=5)) # b[i][j]
                self.b[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j)
                self.b[i][j].insert(0, str(round(random.random()*100)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text=app.b[3][7].get()).grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you store the table in a dictionary and use the built-in [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) module to load and save it.

Here's the code I used to create a initial table dictionary and "pickle it" for testing (in actual use you might want to initialize it to empty or zero values):

```
import pickle
from pprint import pprint
import random

# Create table
table = {}
filename = 'table.pkl'
height = 4
width = 10
for i in range(height):
    table[i] = [round(random.random()*100) for _ in range(width)]

with open(filename, 'wb') as output:
    pickle.dump(table, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

pprint(table)
print('table created')
```

Output showing values in table:

```
{0: [75, 68, 51, 27, 3, 99, 50, 33, 99, 63],
 1: [92, 79, 79, 66, 41, 18, 57, 9, 45, 75],
 2: [34, 75, 67, 92, 38, 93, 28, 76, 75, 38],
 3: [20, 10, 43, 48, 39, 16, 34, 75, 80, 16]}
table created
```

You can then load the data in the pickled file in the `App.__init__()` method and use it as shown:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Tkinter.Frame(master)

        self.data_readout = Tkinter.Button(frame,
                                text="Collect Data", bd=10, height=2, width=10,
                                command=lambda: self.dataReadout(self.table_values))
        self.data_readout.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.table_values = Tkinter.LabelFrame(frame,
                                text="Values", borderwidth=10,
                                relief=Tkinter.GROOVE, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.table_values.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        # Read table.
        with open('table.pkl', 'rb') as infile:
            table = pickle.load(infile)

        # Use table.
        height = 4
        width = 10
        for i in range(height): #Rows
            for j in range(width): #Columns
                b = Tkinter.Entry(self.table_values, text="", width=5)
                b.grid(row=i, column=j)
                b.insert(0, str(table[i][j]))

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

    def dataReadout(self, frame):
        rowArr = []
        colArr = []
        info = frame.children.values()
        for children in frame.children.values():
            info = children.grid_info()
            print(info)
            for i in info:
                print(i)
```

Screenshot of app running. Note that the values being displayed are the same as those that were printed when the table was first created.

[image: Screenshot of app running]

After the values in table are updated, if you wish you can easily update the associated file by via the same `pickle.dump()` function that was used in the code that initially created the pickled table.